# Unity MonoBehaviour Singleton

Tags: design-patterns, unity-game-engine

Normally you can create a Singleton like so:

```
public class Single
{
    public static Single _instance;

    public static Single GetInstance(){...}
}
```

The problem is how do you create this when you generalize the MonoBehaviour class in Unity?

```
public class Single : MonoBehaviour
{
}
```

Regular code above won't work.

edit: Yes problem was that I can't call new on MonoBehaviour.

Comment: Although good link, my post is less generalized than that link you provided.

Comment: In the link you provide the answer is for a class that looks like this: public class MainComponentManger {}. My class looks different because of the MonoBehaviour.

Comment: It's only slightly different: `MainComponentManager` is responsible for creating something like `Single` and attaching it to a global game object. This game object ensures that all singletons derived from `MonoBehaviour` are not removed when loading a new scene. IMHO this is quite important as a singleton should be created once and stay active until the end of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help, for future posts, that you post why or how it is failing to work. However, I ran into the problem in the past, so I know what it is. You cannot initialize the `_instance` with `new` because you cannot call `new` in a **[MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)**.

---

### Solution

In your void `Awake()` add this line:

```
void Awake()
{
    _instance = this;
}
```

---

**Extra Code**

Obviously your `GetInstance()` function will look slightly different now. Notice that we no longer check if instance is equal to null like we would normally do.

```
public static Single GetInstance()
{
    return _instance.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a singleton class that makes easy to create singleton objects. Its is a MonoBehaviour script, so you can use the Coroutines.

Download [this class](https://github.com/bivisss/unity-reusable-singleton/blob/master/Singleton.cs), add it to your project, and create your singleton extending it:

```
public class MySingleton : Singleton<MySingleton> {
  protected MySingleton () {} // guarantee this will be always a singleton only - can't use the constructor!

  public string globalVar;

  void Awake () {
      Debug.Log("Awoke Singleton Instance: " + gameObject.GetInstanceID());
  }
}
```

Now your MySingleton class is a singleton, and you can call it by Instance:

```
MySingleton.Instance.globalVar = "A";
Debug.Log ("globalVar: " + MySingleton.Instance.globalVar);
```

Here is a complete tutorial: http://www.bivis.com.br/2016/05/04/unity-reusable-singleton-tutorial/